# Dockerfile CMD not accepting multiple commands for mysql image

Tags: mysql, docker, cmd

trying to run mysql 5.7 image with datadir flag and also include a bash script at CMD.

```
CMD ["--datadir=/data ; sh db_translations.sh"]
```

What ends up happening is the the container run and creates a folder for mysql called  `data ; sh db_translations.sh`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That `CMD` doesn't really make sense.  With JSON-array syntax the whole thing is a single word, just like as if you typed it in quotes at a shell prompt.  You could change it to shell syntax without the JSON syntax, but `--datadir=/data` isn't a shell command.  What effect are you hoping to get here?  (A container normally only runs a single process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While many containers have `bash` /`sh` as an `ENTRYPOINT` and this would work, in the case of the mysql container, the `ENTRYPOINT` is already a script that just takes the `CMD` offered and doesn't re-`eval`uate  this in script form.

Look at using the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as a location for scripts per docs - https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, though you'll probably need to restructure your script and environment.